# Select Row for Binding Source

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ms-access, data-binding, ado.net

I want to bind a datagridview to a binding source and I was wondering how to record the selected value to the binding source. From what I know so far, there are functions for the binding source to moveup movefirst movedown moveprev. I'm not sure how to really put it in words, but I want to select a value on the datagrid (current row) and have my bindingsource bind to that. This is some code...

```
    private void combo_EditView_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (combo_EditView.Text == "Orders")
        {
            da.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM tbl_Orders", cs);

            editOrderSet.Clear();
            da.Fill(editOrderSet);
            dgv_editView.DataSource = editOrderSet.Tables[0];

            tblEditBS.DataSource = editOrderSet.Tables[0];
            txt_editItem.DataBindings.Clear();
            txt_editItem.DataBindings.Add("Text", tblEditBS, "ItemNum");


        }

        else if (combo_EditView.Text == "Inventory")
        {
            da.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM tbl_Inventory", cs);

            editInventorySet.Clear();
            da.Fill(editInventorySet);
            dgv_editView.DataSource = editInventorySet.Tables[0];
        }
    }

    private void btn_Edit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        da.UpdateCommand = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE tbl_Orders SET ItemNum = @ItemNUm WHERE oid = @oid", cs);
        da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@PO", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txt_editItem.Text.ToString();
        da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("oid", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = editOrderSet.Tables[0].Rows[tblEditBS.Position][0];

        cs_Execute("UPDATE");

        editOrderSet.Clear();
        da.Fill(editOrderSet);
    }

    private void dgv_editView_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        //bind to new cell value row

        tblEditBS.DataSource = editOrderSet.Tables[0];
        txt_editItem.DataBindings.Clear();
        txt_editItem.DataBindings.Add("Text", tblEditBS, "ItemNum");
    }
```

if you are confused, please ask! Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean record the selected value to the binding source?